# nodejs Promise.all returns null on some mongoose promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

i am passing array of mongoose promises and for some reason sometimes customerFindPromise return null, and sometimes it return the requested object. am i doing something wrong here

```
******************** START result0: null result END ********************
 ******************** START result1: { _id: 5a18a637346826574416a588,
doc_fname: 'Bob',
doc_lname: 'Smith',
numOfCases: 1,
__v: 0 } result END ********************
******************** START result2: {"n":1,"ok":1} result END ********************
```

**Code**

```
var customer = {
    doctor_id: 5a18a637346826574416a588,
    cust_fname: 'dfsdf',
    cust_lname: 'sdasd',
    case_type: 'Crowns',
    _id: 5a1cd19438f14164b0087753 
}
test(customerCase);
async function test(customerCase) {

    console.log("******************** customerCaseDelete: "+ customerCase._id +" ********************");
    var _id = customerCase._id;
    var doctor_id = customerCase.doctor_id;
    var query = {_id:_id};

    const customerFindPromise = CustomerCases.findById(_id);
    const customerRemovePromise = CustomerCases.remove(query);
    const doctorUpdatePromise = Doctors.findOneAndUpdate({_id:doctor_id},{'$inc': {'numOfCases': -1}},{new:true});

    await Promise.all([customerFindPromise,doctorUpdatePromise,customerRemovePromise])
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("******************** START result0: "+ result[0] +" result END ********************");
        console.log("******************** START result1: "+ result[1] +" result END ********************");
        console.log("******************** START result2: "+ result[2] +" result END ********************");
        res.json(result);
      }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("******************** START err: "+ err +" err END ********************");
         throw err;
      });
}
```

Comment: your code as posted is invalid, specifically the declaration of `var customer`

Comment: Finding and removing an object with the same id at the same time clearly looks like a classic race condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you are running are asynchronous and won't always run in order. [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) does not change the execution order of the promises either, it just waits for them all to be resolved.

Sometimes `CustomerCases.remove` will execute and resolve before `CustomerCases.findById` so `null` resolves when the document has been removed first.

Wait for the promises to resolve serially before executing the next query, seeing as you are using `async`/`await` it's fairly simple to add:

```
try{
  let find = await CustomerCases.findById(_id)
  console.log(`find: ${find}`)
  let update = await CustomerCases.remove(query)
  console.log(`update: ${update}`)
  let remove = await Doctors.findOneAndUpdate({_id:doctor_id},{'$inc': {'numOfCases': -1}},{new:true})
  console.log(`remove: ${update}`)
  res.json([find, update, remove])
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
  throw err // next(err)?
}
```

Try bluebirds [`Promise.each`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) if you need a serial execution helper.

Comment: Promises do not "run", and there is no "execution" in `Promise.all` so there's no order for that either.

Comment: @Bergi better terminology?

Comment: Thank you @Matt, i thought by adding await to promises it won't execute all promises at the same time. is there away to add Promise.all, and is it necessary for this situation.

Comment: @Matt thank you your solution works, what if one of the mongoose function fails, is it possible to revert the functions that got executed

Comment: Mongo doesn't do transactions out of the box. You would need to manually roll back the data you want depending on the error.